# Spritekit Swift particle SKEmitterNode add remove

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, particle-system, skemitternode

so this is nice for create a particle, but whats the right way to remove it , after the duration, sparkEmmiter.particleLifetime do not remove it automatically

```
let sparkEmmiter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MyParticle.sks")
sparkEmmiter.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2 - 200)
sparkEmmiter.name = "sparkEmmitter"
sparkEmmiter.zPosition = 1
sparkEmmiter.targetNode = self
sparkEmmiter.particleLifetime = 1

self.addChild(sparkEmmiter)
```

this solutions produce simulator crash

```
  var re = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
  var remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
  var seq = SKAction.sequence([re , remove])
  sparkEmmiter.runAction(seq)
```

Comment: run an action with waitForDuration and a runBlock which then removes the emitter node

Comment: no i have already tried this solution and get simulator crash can see my solution in edited previous post